# Gradient created in a style sheet look different from those created via a QBrush?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am using Qt 4.8.5 with a tree view and I would like to color the background of some items with a gradient depending on what the user is doing. One possibility is that the user moves the mouse over a tree item. The only way to set the background to a gradient in this case is to define a style sheet like that and to set it as the tree views style sheet:

```
QTreeView::item:hover { background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
stop: 0 rgb(255, 255, 255), stop: 1 rgb (0, 255, 255);
border: 1px solid rgb (0, 255, 255); }
```

This works.

There are situations where I would like to mark tree items the same way, even when the mouse is not placed over this tree item (there is a 3D view and some items of the 3D view correspondent to tree items – I would like to highlight the tree view items, when the user points on those items in the 3D view).

This is also possible. I the data(…) method of the document tree model, I return a brush that I have created like this:

```
QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 0, 1);
gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(255, 255, 255));
gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(0, 255, 255));
QBrush brush(gradient);
```

This also works. The only problem is, that the gradient defined with the brush is much different from the gradient defined with the style sheet, even though the numbers are the same (actually in this example the complete background is white – but when I play with the numbers I realize that it is indeed a gradient, but not the one I had expected).

Could someone explain me the reason?

I thought that this could be the case because the QLinearGradient interprets the x1, x2, y1, y2 value as pixels. Does the style sheet interpret these values as relative values? I have played around with the coordinate mode of the gradient, but this did not help.

How can I make both gradients look the same? Or should I get rid of those style sheets and define everything with QBrush’s?

Another question: my impression is, that those Qt style-sheets are not really well-thought-out. Is this just because I don't know yet how to use them or is this really the case?

I will try to make the problem clearer by adding some screen shots (I should have done that immediately). The coordinate mode of the following QLinearGradient instances has been set to QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode:

This is the tree item with the gradient defined by the style sheet:
[image: This is the tree item with the gradient defined by the style sheet.]

This is the tree item with the gradient defined by the QBrush with a QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1):
[image: This is the tree item with the gradient defined by the QBrush with a QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1)]

This is the tree item with the gradient defined by the QBrush with a QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1):
[image: This is the tree item with the gradient defined by the QBrush with a QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1)]

My problem is: neither of the QBrush/QLinearGradient combinations looks like the gradient defined by the style sheet. Is anyone out there who has managed to create a QBrush/QLinearGradient that looks like the style sheet gradient?

Comment: There should be no "Another question" in one question. One question should focus on one question here on Stack Overflow. The first paragraph is also needless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can **NOT** change the [`CoordinateMode`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgradient.html#CoordinateMode-enum) of your gradient in Qt CSS `qlineargradient(...)`.

It is always `QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode`, [see the code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qcssparser.cpp.html#873).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [`CoordinateMode`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgradient.html#CoordinateMode-enum) of your gradient. Set it to `QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode` if you want it to be relative to the bounding rectangle,  like it is in the stylesheets.

From the [stylesheet reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-property-types) docs: *Gradients are specified in Object Bounding Mode.*

One thing that is wrong in your code, is the usage of [`QGradient::setColorAt`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgradient.html#setColorAt). You are using `255` as the position parameter, even though the acceptable range is between 0 and 1. You should be receiving a warning message for this.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! You are completely right, but still it does not help. The version I have posted here was one version of my playing-around with parameters. When I set the coordinate mode to ObjectBoundingMode and change the wrong range number to 1, the brush is displayed as plain white. When I change the gradient definition to QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 1, 1); then I see that the brush is indeed a gradient, but a rotated one, which is not what I want to have.

Answer (score 0):

The `QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode` option does not work as expected for item view items. I was able to accomplish a similar task in a QTableView by using the default mode and pixel coordinates. The coordinates are relative to the item's visual rectangle. In my case, I have access to the view and was able to use `QAbstractItemView::visualRect()`.

```
if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
{
  QColor c = ...
  QRectF r = table()->visualRect(mi); 
  QLinearGradient g(0,0, 0,r.height());
  g.setColorAt(0, c.lighter(200));
  g.setColorAt(1, c);
  return QBrush(g);
}
```